# Use of semi-colon in a list with last item having a specific condition

Tags: semicolons

I am dealing with a local ordinance worded in the following way:

> Commercial farming and agricultural activities, such as citrus groves (as well as other fruits); forestry; plant nurseries; truck farms; fish pools; animal feedlots; hatching and raising of poultry; production of eggs; raising of livestock (hogs, horses, cattle, sheep, etc.), shall require a minimum of five acres.

Does the last part “shall require a minimum of five acres” apply to the entire list or just the raising of livestock?

Comment: This is more a question for a lawyer than a linguist.  See [this article](https://www.loweringthebar.net/2017/03/the-oxford-comma-use-it.html) for a famous example.

Comment: I think it should be commas throughout.

Comment: When we assume it applies to the last part , what then will the other items in the list mean ? What should we do with those items ? What is the ordinance trying to convey ? Why are those items (not other items) listed ? **Logical Conclusion** : It will apply to the whole list ! **Grammatical Conclusion** : It is out of scope of the ordinance makers !

Comment: I can't imagine any way of parsing this that doesn't treat everything from "such as" to "etc.)" as parenthetical. The list is just examples of "commercial farming and agricultural activities".

Comment: Normally, commas (not semicolons) are used to separate items on a list. But semicolons are used instead of commas as the separators whenever one or more of the list items themselves require a comma. For instance: "We visited our cousins, who live in a big house; our grandparents; and my uncle."

Comment: It's a horrid sentence but only the most desperate person would deny that "shall require a minimum of five acres" applies to the entire list. If it doesn't apply then what is the point of the rest of the sentence? Give up posting here and go see a lawyer.

Comment: There is no justification for the comma immediately before the word "shall".

Answer (score 0):

The list of specific activities are examples of commercial farming and agricultural activities. It should be treated as parenthetical, and doesn't affect what the verb phrase refers to. It's essentially equivalent to the two sentences:

> Commercial farming and agricultural activities shall require a minimum of five acres.
> Examples include: citrus groves (as well as other fruits), forestry, plant nurseries, truck farms, fish pools, animal feedlots, hatching and raising of poultry, production of eggs, and raising of livestock (hogs, horses, cattle, sheep, etc.

Notice that when the list is not set off from the rest of the sentence with commas we use commas to separate the list items rather than semicolons.

The original sentence would probably be easier to understand if the "such as" phrase were actually in parentheses, rather than set off with commas. By definition, anything in parentheses is parenthetical.